# Framework 7 Vue how to stop Firebase from listening to changes when on different pages?

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, html-framework-7

Suppose I have `pageA` where I listen for a firebase document changes

```
export default {
  mounted() {
    this.$f7ready(() => {
      this.userChanges();
    })
  },
  methods: {
    userChanges() {
      Firebase.database().ref('users/1').on('value', (resp) => {
        console.log('use data has changed');
      });
    }
  }
}
```

Then I go to `pageB` using `this..$f7.views.current.router.navigate('/pageB/')`

If on `pageB` I make changes to the `/users/1` firebase route I see this ,message in the console: `use data has changed`, even though I'm on a different page.

Any way to avoid this behavior, maybe unload the page somehow?

I tried to stop the listener before navigating away from `pageA` using [Firebase.off()](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/query/off.html) but that seems to break a few other things.

Comment: What does `.off` break? When you pass reference to previously registered handler, it should remove only that listener..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you properly removing the listener for that specific database reference? You'll have to save the referenced path on a dedicated variable to do so:

```
let userRef
export default {
    mounted() {
        this.$f7ready(() => {
            this.userChanges();
        })
    },
    methods: {
        userChanges() {
            userRef = Firebase.database().ref('users/1')
            userRef.on('value', (resp) => {
                console.log('use data has changed');
            });
        },
        detachListener() {
            userRef.off('value')
        }
    }
}
```

That way you only detach the listener for that specific reference. Calling it on the parent, would remove all listeners as the documentation specifies:

> You can remove a single listener by passing it as a parameter to
>   off(). Calling off() on the location with no arguments removes all
>   listeners at that location.

More on that topic here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#detach_listeners